# Getting MSBuild and CruiseControl .NET to build and deploy VS2010 database projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, gac, database-project

I almost have a NAnt script together that will build and deploy VS2010 database projects, but one error stands in my way:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.TSqlTasks.targets(56,5): error MSB4062: The "SqlBuildTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks.Sql, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks.Sql, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [xxx]
Failed to start MSBuild.
External Program Failed: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe (return code was 1)
```

I can see that the `Microsoft.Data.Schema` assemblies are not in the MSIL GAC on the build server - is there any clean way to do this without a full-freight installation of VS2010 on the build server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the curious, I asked Barclay Hill at Microsoft who answered this for me:

> You can’t build database projects on
>   machines unless they have VS or TFS
>   2010 installed on them.  It is not a
>   supported scenario.  You can deploy
>   database project build outputs without
>   VS/TFS installed using vsdbcmd.   The
>   only way to do this and be in line
>   with the licensing and support is to
>   install a local copy of VS Pro or
>   higher on your build box if not using
>   TFS.

Comment: TFS is great.  But it is NOT the ONLY Build Tool out there.  My rule is to NOT have VS200x or 201x on the build box.  So all the dependencies aren't "hidden"......  (Not mad at you (Brandon) of course, thanks for the info.))  Microsoft helps me make a living, but man , every once in a while they get my goat.  PS Upvote for response.